# Prove that, if $a,b,c \geq 1$, then $\frac{3ab+2c+1}{a+b}+\frac{3bc+2a+1}{b+c}+\frac{3ca+2b+1}{c+a} \geq 9$.

Tags: inequality

**the question**

Prove that, if $a,b,c \geq 1$, then

$\frac{3ab+2c+1}{a+b}+\frac{3bc+2a+1}{b+c}+\frac{3ca+2b+1}{c+a} \geq 9$.

**the idea**

I know that these arent really helpful ideas, but as you know we have to use an inequality theorem to demonstrate this....I thought of the inequality of means, but when I tried the equality case it didn't work, so we I can't show the inequality by the inequality of means

Then I thought of Bermstrong or CBS and tried writing LHS in different forms that are probably useful.

I always get stuck at this kind of problem, when I get to show inequality. Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: are we given that a,b,c>0?

Comment: what are Bermstrong and CBS?

Comment: This isn't true. Say a=b=c=0.1

Comment: Blitzer is correct.  Did you mean $a, b, c \ge 1$?

Comment: @Blitzer i edite the question. Sorry for my mispelling

Comment: @Dan yes this was what i meant. Sorry for my mispelling. I edited

Comment: @IONELABUCIU: You need to change it in the title, too.

Comment: @Blitzer Bermstrong and CBS (also known as Cauchy-Bermstrong-Schwarz inequality) are 2 inequalities that are usually used for demonstrating inequalitys. You can search them on interenet, im sure you will find them.

Comment: But this inequality looks wrong too. Take $a=b=c=100$.

Comment: @Aig it seems i forgot the difference between leq and geq. Sorry again

Comment: Suggest you dumbass it - ie multiply through to clear out the denominators.

Comment: @Blitzer i tried doing so already but i have to addmit i got lost in numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fact that
$$3ab+1\ge 2ab+2\ge 2a+2b \hspace{1cm} \text{for }a,b\ge 1$$
Then use C-S inequality
$$\sum_{\text{sym}}\frac{3ab+2c+1}{a+b} \ge\sum_{\text{sym}}\frac{2a + 2b +2c}{a+b} = 2(a+b+c)  \sum_{\text{sym}}\frac{1}{a+b} \ge 9$$
The equality occurs if and only if $a = b=c =1$.

Comment: May i ask why $2ab+2\geq 2a+2b$

Comment: @IONELABUCIU because $(a-1)(b-1)\ge 0$